# Android ExoPlayer - cannot load audio from local storage with MediaItem

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I'm using ExoPlayer `2.14.1` for short audio files playback with methods:

```
val player = SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(context, fftAudioRendererFactory).build()
player.setMediaItem(MediaItem.fromUri(uri))
player.prepare()
```

When I load audio from URL (`https://...myfile.aac`), it plays correctly. However when I try to load the same audio but from a **file in local storage**:

`/data/user/0/my.app.name/cache/audios/myfile.aac`

The file cannot get loaded. I get below warning:

> MessageQueue: Handler (android.os.Handler) {5b7060e} sending message
> to a Handler on a dead thread
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Handler (android.os.Handler) {5b7060e} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
> at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:560)
> at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java:778)
> at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:727)
> at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:697)
> at android.os.Handler.sendMessage(Handler.java:635)
> at android.os.Message.sendToTarget(Message.java:468)
> at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.prepare(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:283)

I tried different URI for file, like `file:/` or `file:///` but nothing helped. Any tips?

Comment: Even though I didn't see the key `Exception` in your error log, but from your file path it looks like you are accessing the file from the public storage?

Comment: No the file is inside internal storage of my app, it plays OK with MediaPlayer

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!

As [ExoPlayer docs](https://exoplayer.dev/progressive.html) say for .aac files it's necessary to set constant bitrate seeking. In order to do that I had to create `SimpleExoPlayer` with a ExtractorsFactory argument like this:

```
private val extractorsFactory = DefaultExtractorsFactory().setConstantBitrateSeekingEnabled(true)
private val player = SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(context, extractorsFactory).build()
```

For some reasons .aac files loaded from url (https) works without bitrate seeking setting - maybe it does some convertion in the middle.